# Using named placeholders on query

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I'm trying to run this query:

```
SELECT round(ST_Distance_Sphere(
    ((ST_GeomFromText('POINT(:lat :lon)',4326))),
    (SELECT wkb_geometry FROM coastline ORDER BY wkb_geometry <->
    ((ST_GeomFromText('POINT(:lat :lon)',4326))) LIMIT 1 )
    ))
as Distance;
```

As you can see, I'm trying to use named placeholders on it, but I get this error:

```
Warning: PDOStatement::bindParam(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: :lat
Warning: PDOStatement::bindParam(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: :lon
```

I tried not repeating the placeholders (using lat, lat2, lon and lon2, just in case), using half named placeholders and half fixed numbers. Neither of them worked. Instead, I tried it like this:

```
ST_GeomFromText('POINT(".$lat." ".$lon.")',4326)
```

And it works, but I want to use named placeholders. Does someone know which kind of dark magic is preventing me from doing so?

I don't know if that would be better on stackoverflow, but since I'm having this problem only with postgis, I thought it might be better to ask here.

Comment: I don't think this works in postgresql as you expect it to - see this https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75142/postgresql-equivalent-of-mysql-query-variables we use Common Table Expressions in the place of variables, and SELECTS on the CTE's when we need them...

Comment: Are you talking about within a psql prompt, ie, setting the value of same variable, and then substituting into the queries, or using some programming language? It can be done in psql, I just want to make sure I'm answering the right question.

Comment: @JohnPowellakaBarça I don't quite understand what you're asking right now. I'm just trying to use named placeholders, assigning them a value from a variable before running the query.

Comment: Where are you runing the query from? The command line, ie, a psql prompt or a GUI (like pgAdmin) or a programming language. This makes a big difference to how placeholders work.

Comment: I'm running it on the linux terminal, logging as psql -U user.

Comment: OK, so I have answered how to do if from a psql prompt in a terminal. Hope that is what you were looking for?

Comment: @JohnPowellakaBarça Yes! I had to play a bit around with it, but it works perfectly, thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a little bit obscure, but based on the [set command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html), you can assign a value to a variable in a **psql** environment using this syntax:

```
\set variable value
```

And then use it by using

```
:value
```

as the placeholder. For example,

```
\set geom ST_MakePoint(0, 0)
SELECT ST_Buffer(:geom, 10);
```

**Note:** If you use functions such as ST_GeomFromText, where the argument is contained in apostrophes, you have to escape the apostrophes, eg,

```
\set geom ST_Geomfromtext('''POINT(0 0)''')
SELECT ST_Buffer(:geom, 10);
```

Personally, I find it cleaner to use ST_MakePoint, than ST_GeomFromText, so you could (partially) rewrite you query above as:

```
\set lon 50
\set lat -2

SELECT 
     ST_Distance_Sphere(
          ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(:lon, :lat), 4326), 
          ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(:lon + 1, :lat + 1), 4326)
   );
```

where, as you can see, as lon and lat are variables, you can even add to them. Obviously, I don't have access to your tables, so this isn't actually a rewrite of you query, but you get the point.

Comment: De res. But I'm English, just escaped the weather. :D